# Angular: Subscribe not detecting changes therefore my view not getting updated

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have two components, one of them is a child route inside a  of the main component html.

Whenever I select checkboxes of categories in the main component, I am assigning them to a variable(string array) in service. And in the child route, I am subscribing to an observable of this service variable. My goal is to update the child route's view to display the books of those categories only.

So shouldn't I be seeing the logs as and when the value of service variable gets changed (Because I have given console.log() in child component)? 
Doesn't subscribe get updated value everytime the value changes?
And finally, does subscribe call the ngOnChanges() method? (To update the view)

My Code:-
Parent Component.html:-

```
  <div class="ui-g-12">
    <p-checkbox
      name="categories"
      value="Science Fiction"
      label="Science Fiction"
      [(ngModel)]="selectedCategories"
      (onChange)="categoryFilterSelect()"
    ></p-checkbox>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-g-12">
    <p-checkbox
      name="categories"
      value="Horror"
      label="Horror"
      [(ngModel)]="selectedCategories"
      (onChange)="categoryFilterSelect()"
    ></p-checkbox>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-g-12">
    <p-checkbox
      name="categories"
      value="Suspense"
      label="Suspense"
      [(ngModel)]="selectedCategories"
      (onChange)="categoryFilterSelect()"
    ></p-checkbox>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-g-12">
    <p-checkbox
      name="categories"
      value="Romance"
      label="Romance"
      [(ngModel)]="selectedCategories"
      (onChange)="categoryFilterSelect()"
    ></p-checkbox>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-g-12">
    <p-checkbox
      name="categories"
      value="Action"
      label="Action"
      [(ngModel)]="selectedCategories"
      (onChange)="categoryFilterSelect()"
    ></p-checkbox>
  </div>
  <div style="margin-top: 10%">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
```

Parent Component.ts:-

```
selectedCategories: string[] = [];
 //...

 categoryFilterSelect(){
    this.userService._filterByGenre = this.selectedCategories;
  }
```

second component's ts:-(routed into  of Parent Component.html)

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  allBooks: Book[] = [];
  selectedCategories: string[];
  filteredBooks: Book[];

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    //initially display all books
    this.userService.getAllBooks().subscribe(data => {
      this.allBooks = data;
      this.filteredBooks = this.allBooks;
    });


    //This part not working
    this.userService.filterByGenre.subscribe(data => {
      this.selectedCategories = data;

      //this line not working
      console.log(this.selectedCategories);


      //perform filter logic here and update the filteredBooks array based 
      // onselected categories
    }
    );
  }
}
```

second component.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="child" *ngFor="let book of filteredBooks">
....
  </div>
</div>
```

service.ts

```
export class UserService {

  _filterByGenre: string[] = [];
  public get filterByGenre(): Observable<string[]> {
    return of(this._filterByGenre);
  }
}
```

console output:- 
[] 
(Because initially no categories are selected so this is logged).

My Git Repo:-
https://github.com/Lucifer-77/ATL

Comment: `this.userService.filterByGenre...` -- is this a typo?

Comment: No, why do you say so?

Comment: If i replace with this.userService._filterByGenre.subscribe(..., it gives error saying subscribe does not exist on type string[] ,,,and this.userService.filterByGenre().subscribe(...., gives error "Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'Observable<string[]>' has no compatible call signatures.",,,, the existing line gives no error while compiling(using vs code btw with all lints and extensions for ts)

Comment: would you mind  creating an example on stackblitz.

Comment: I already tried to upload on stackblitz but the project fails to find src and also backend needs to be run separately

Comment: @indrajeet I have added my git repo link. Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Lucifer, the things don't work as you think. Angular is not magical. Don't worry about it, it's a common mistake at first. When you subscribe to an Observable, Angular not put a "big brother" to see what happens to the data. e.g. when we make a subscription of httpClient.get(url) that call to a dbs, any change of dbs Angular don't take account of this. (it can not do it).

So you need create a service that say that Angular take account the changes: you need make use of Subject of similar. Let me show a service that work

```
  private _filterByGenre:string[];

  private filterByGenreSource = new Subject<any>();
  filterByGenreObservable=this.filterByGenreSource.asObservable();

  get filterByGenre()
  {
    return this._filterByGenre
  }
  set filterByGenre(value)  //when we use dataService.filterBtGenre=...
  {
    this._filterByGenre=value;           //equal to the private variable
    this.filterByGenreSource.next(value) //say to Angular that something change
  }
```

You can subscribe to filterByGenreObservable

```
this.dataService.filterByGenreObservable.subscribe(data => {
  this.selectedCategories = [...data]; //(*)
});

//(*) is we make simply this.selectedCategories=data, we can not see the data change
//so, I used the spread operator
```

If we make something like

```
this.dataService.filterByGenre = this.selectedCategories;
```

As we are using a setter, emit a new value

Well, I don't use p-checkbox, but you can be the code of this answer in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gvfhfk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Update** well, Obviously we want to make "something" when change the categories.

Imagine we has an array called allBooks, and we want filterted by categories selected. But first we are going to change the data we send to the user service to make more similar to p-checkbox, so I change my function categoryFileterSelect to send in an array not [true,false,false,true] else ["Horror","Science Fiction"]

```
categoryFilterSelect() {
    this.dataService.filterByGenre =
      this.options.filter((x, index) => this.selectedCategories[index]);

  }
```

So, We can write

```
this.userService.filterByGenreObservable.subscribe(
  data => {
    this.filteredBooks=this.allBooks.filter(x=>data.indexOf(x.genre)>=0)
  },
  error => null,
  () => console.log("error")
);
```

Well, I want to make at first observable a call with the value of this.userService.filterByGenre, so I go to use rxjs operator startWith so, finally my subscription becomes like

```
this.userService.filterByGenreObservable.pipe(
  startWith(this.userService.filterByGenre))
  .subscribe(
  data => {
    this.filteredBooks=data?this.allBooks.filter(x=>data.indexOf(x.genre)>=0)
                           :this.allBooks
  },
  error => null,
  () => console.log("error")
);
```

Comment: Thanks Eliseo for the explanation but this did not work for me either

Comment: I have modified my code exactly like yours. Here's my git repo https://github.com/Lucifer-77/ATL

Comment: @LuciferMorningstar, you need make "something" when you subscribe to filerByGenreObservable into subscribe function. I updated my answer and put it in the https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-krms7b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: Thanks a ton Eliseo, It is finally working. Now finally I can proceed with the development. I had never heard of startwith() or Subject. I would like to learn these concepts and angular as a whole in more depth. From where did you learn angular? Can you point me to a source/sources where I can learn these concepts and more??? Thanks again a lot

Comment: @LuciferMorningstar, Yo don't beleive me, but I just take count that in Rxjs 6, you needn't use a Subject and the subject as Observable `filterByGenreSource = new Subject<any>();` and `filterByGenreObservable=this.filterByGenreSource.asObservable();` you can simply use `filterByGenreSource = new Subject<any>();` and subscribe to filterByGenreSource directly. There' a serie of articles in https://medium.com/@natelapinski/learning-observables-part-1-arrays-14480816eb61 that create an Observable, but you can store an idea: An observable is a function that return a value when we subscribe

Comment: To create an observable, we can use the Contructor of Rxjs: Subject, of,... (we import {...} from 'rxjs' and modify the response using the operators of Rxjs import {..} from 'rxjs/operators'. About Rxjs you has, e.g. https://www.learnrxjs.io/

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the following call of filterByGenre() in the second component.

```
this.userService.filterByGenre().subscribe((data:string[]) => {
  this.selectedCategories = data;

  console.log(this.selectedCategories);


  //perform filter logic here and update the filteredBooks array based 
  // onselected categories
}
```

Comment: No, it gives error "Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'Observable<string[]>' has no compatible call signatures"

Comment: In your template <p-checkbox> has string value and it's model (selectedCategories) having string[] type, make sure that when you change the state of p-checkbox type off selectedCategories is still preserved.

Comment: it is, if I put log in the method categoryFilterSelect() { console.log(this.userService._filterByGenre); },,,,, it gives me correct output Like as follows "(4) ["Horror", "Science Fiction", "Suspense", "Romance"]" on selecting 4 categories