# Component with table not updating

Tags: angular

I have a simple CRUD app with Angular 8 front end and spring boot back-end.
I have a user-list component which has a table and a create-user component which is a form.
The create-user component adds a user entry to the database then redirects to the user-list. The problem:New entry not immediately visible on table after redirect. The problem is hit and miss. One time it works as it should and one time it doesn't

Solution: Redirect to list on subscribe

Comment: If someone is interested in helping I can offer as many details as needed

Comment: please provide more info.

Comment: We can't help you find the bug in your code if you don't post your code. My guess is that you redirect before receiving the response of the insertion, instead of waiting to have the response before redirecting.

Comment: please share your html code and ts code.

Comment: susbcribing is not magic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56814989/angular-subscribe-not-detecting-changes-therefore-my-view-not-getting-updated/56816633#56816633